# Como posso visualizar um objeto AxesSubplot da mesma forma que acontece com pyplot.show()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Estou aprendendo a mexer com pandas e após obter um DataFrame, o próximo passo foi obter um gráfico desse DataFrame "supermarket":

```
supermarket.loc[:10, 'Total'].plot(figsize=(14, 6))
```

Isto resulta num objeto destes:

Acontece que este objeto não tem o método show() para o poder visualizar. Não há forma "direta" de visualizar um objeto destes?
Já li que poderá ser enviado para um Tkinter.Canvas mas ainda não entendi como...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo objeto `Axes` possui um objeto `Figure` que o contém (partindo do princípio do que foi inicializado de maneira correta). Um `Figure` pode conter múltiplos `Axes`, no caso de uma figura com mais de um gráfico. Para exibir um `Figure` na tela, use:

```
figure.show()
```

Caso você só tenha acesso ao `Axes`, é possível pegar o seu `Figure` correspondente com:

```
ax.get_figure()
```

Vale notar que o módulo `pyplot` é um atalho que tem como objetivo facilitar essa interface de elementos: você pode pegar o `Figure` atual (isto é, o último que foi modificado) com `pyplot.gcf()`, plotar no `Axes` atual com `pyplot.plot()` e mostrar o `Figure` atual com `pyplot.show()`. Acessar os elementos gráficos `Figure` e `Axes` diretamente é mais trabalhoso e só deve ser utilizado se você precisar mesmo desse controle.

No seu caso, chamar `DataFrame.plot()` é ainda mais alto nível do que usar o `pyplot`: o próprio pandas se preocupa em chamar/inicializar os elementos do matplotlib para você. Em geral, para evitar a verbosidade de algo como:

```
ax = df.plot( ... )
ax.get_figure().show()
```

Se prefere:

```
df.plot( ... )
plt.show()
```

Tendo previamente importado o `pyplot` com a convenção `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

[Aqui tem uma descrição mais detalhada dos elementos que compõem um `Axis`](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#parts-of-a-figure).

[Aqui fala um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do módulo `pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related).

Comment: Ótimo. Resultou, é isso mesmo. Já tinha lido bastantes documentos sem conseguir obter resultados. Tu conseguiste-me explicar o básico e encaminhar-me no sentido correto para ler o que é preciso. Agora o resto é comigo. Obrigado.